# How do I apply a patch file?

Tags: version-control

I downloaded a patch file from mailhandler module and need to apply the changes in order to fix the problem of pop3 accounts not deleting emails after download (import).  How do I install it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581644/how-to-apply-a-patch

Comment: Questions asking for links to resources are off-topic as per help center.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here are a few links that may help you learn more about patching:

- [Applying a Patch Manually](http://drupal.org/node/534548)
- [Making a Drupal patch with Git](http://drupal.org/node/707484) (also covers applying)
- [HowTo: How to apply a patch to a contributed module - Beginner's version (Windows)](http://drupal.org/node/620014)
- [Apply Patches on Windows](http://drupal.org/node/60179) (more methods)
- [Apply patches on Mac OS](http://drupal.org/node/60818)
- [How to apply patches for Drupal modules and files](http://www.lightrains.com/blog/apply-patches-drupal-modules-files)

Comment: Your third link is what I needed.  I had seen all of the other links and didn't find them basic enough.  The one that you found is indeed the one I was looking for.  It's very detailed.  Thanks.

Comment: great, thanks for how to Applying a Patch Manually info !!!

Answer (score 7):

There's a description in every module under the tab version control. Scroll down to the title "Applying a patch" to find a description about applying patches with git.

Comment: Thanks, I learned something here too.  the "tab version control" used to be called someting else, "Git instructions".  Thanks.  Now, if I only knew what GIT meant!