# How to install a patch to drupal 7

Tags: version-control

I recently exprience one problem that requires a patch. I downloaded that file .patch, but have no idea how properly to install that to my hosted website.

Comment: Check out http://drupal.org/patch

Comment: Check out this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23347/how-do-i-apply-a-patch-file#23356

Answer (score 6):

If you can shell into the account, you

```
cd /var/www/somewhere/docroot/sites/all/module
patch -p1 < /path/to/the/patchfile
```

Depending on how the patch was rolled, you may need to adjust the number after the -p to get it to apply properly.  The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch) can give you more details.

If you can't shell into the host, then you need to downloads the files(s), apply the patch locally and then upload them.  This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517257/how-do-i-apply-a-diff-patch-on-windows) give guidance, or you can cut to the chase and check out [TortoiseMerge](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/TortoiseMerge.html).