# where and how to manually apply patch?

Tags: drush, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I apply a patch file?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23347/how-do-i-apply-a-patch-file)

It is obvious latest colorbox plugin needs patching because even with drush install it is not working to load images and I've been at it all day, literally.

So found this http://drupal.org/files/patch-colorbox-1_3_21-2.patch  which is recommended for the drush install of colorbox plugin with only the one colorbox folder.

But where and how do I patch it?

Very kind volunteers have been trying to help throughout the day but I am yet to get this fixed.

Comment: If you mean _without_ git then everything you need to know is on the [Applying Patches](http://drupal.org/patch/apply) documentation page

Comment: thanks but I can't see where the module needs patching, the changes are already there.

Comment: none of this makes sense, i am at my wits end and really there is no-one who can help even though plenty have tried

Comment: It sounds like the patch file you've got doesn't apply to the version of the module you've got, so only the maintainers of that patch/module are going to be able to help really. Without reviewing the entire diff for the date ranges in question I'm not sure how anyone without prior knowledge would be able to help

Comment: it is latest release of colorbox and plugin for drupal 7.19

Comment: the developers have been discussing it a few days ago and how i found patch but it is not fixing my issue of no images loading and js file not being  found

Comment: I understand, but that doesn't mean that the patch was necessarily created for that exact version of the module. If it wasn't, or parts of that patch have already been incorporated, then the patch file won't apply any more and you'll get errors. I'm afraid I can't help any further (I don't know anything about the colorbox module), you need to use the existing issue(s) on Drupal.org to contact the module maintainers

Answer (score 0):

You could either do it through the patch program or git. you have a good documentation [here](http://drupal.org/patch/apply)

Or do it manually.

```
  --- colorbox.module.old   2013-01-17 12:36:37.000000000 -0700
    +++ colorbox.module 2013-01-17 12:35:46.000000000 -0700
    @@ -80,9 +80,9 @@
         'download url' => 'http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox',
         'path' => 'colorbox',
         'version arguments' => array(
    -      'file' => 'colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js',
    +      'file' => 'jquery.colorbox-min.js',
           'pattern' => '@ColorBox v([0-9\.a-z]+)@',
    -      'lines' => 1,
    +      'lines' => 2,
         ),
         'files' => array(
           'js' => array(
```

What this says is in the colorbox.module file and find the line which says

```
'file' => 'colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js',
```

replace that with

```
'file' => 'jquery.colorbox-min.js',
```

and find the line with

```
'lines' => 1,
```

and change that to

```
'lines' => 2,
```

@@ -80,9 +80,9 @@ this tells you that you would be looking some were near line number 80.

Comment: Mohammed, do you think this will fix the issue of images not loading and js file not being found?

Comment: It depends on lots of other things. Some time it could be the file permission. as you have mentioned in the other post. you apache server does not have the permission to access the file. Have you tried installing it through the interface rather than through drush?

Comment: Well I see no 'file'=> 'colorbox/ only what it should be file => nameofile.js...i've tried 8 hours worth of ways.

Comment: do you know how to use irc?

Comment: yes i do know how to use irc.

Comment: thanks Mohammed anyway for giving your time, I appreciate it but the above did not solve it for me.

Comment: hop into irc #drupal

Comment: am in there now but # is dead

Comment: what is your id? mine is shameemkm

Comment: might just try uploading backups before upgrades- see how i go- thanks again.

Comment: i don't see you there in the list ...mine is _ann

Comment: how do u msg on here sorry? my email is yabbitdesign@gmail.com maybe when you are not too busy you could help that way? i do not expect help.

Comment: http://webchat.freenode.net/ i am on web irc