# Log out is not redirecting to front page

Tags: 7, users

I have a problem where once the user log out, the page is not redirecting to login page(home page) instead it is redirecting to the profile page.

I have used login destination module to redirect the user to profile page once login. The same path is taking even for log out.
If I remove the login destination module this problem is not happening.

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1):

It is a [bug](https://drupal.org/node/1964602) in the module which already submitted in the module [issue queue](https://drupal.org/project/issues/login_destination). But you can solve it by applying this [patch](https://drupal.org/files/1964602-1-login_destination-front_redirect.patch) in the module. if you don't know to apply patch then check [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23347/how-do-i-apply-a-patch-file).