# How to patch module files with netbeans 7.4?

Tags: version-control

Trying to apply patch https://drupal.org/files/webform_preview-435232_1.patch
to webform 7.x-3.19 via Netbeans tool - apply dif-patch. Downloaded this patch and put into drupal root directory. When applying patch to module files see the following: "The patch cannot be applied in the selected context". Module files are in Netbeans project and all paths are properly set. The code to which patch changes are applied exists in the target file, so what else problems can be?

Thanks!

Comment: By curiosity, why not use git?

Comment: Can you provide me with a link on using git to patch drupal?

Comment: https://drupal.org/patch/apply

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23347/how-do-i-apply-a-patch-file?rq=1

Comment: @Wtower if you think it's a duplicate, flag as such.

Comment: @Mołot thanks, kind of similar but not duplicate I would say

Comment: @Wtower duplicates no longer have to be exact. But if you don't think they are, don't flag. You just dropped a link without explanation, so I assumed you simply forgot flagging.

Comment: thanks, I'll read this, but I am still curious about the solution in Netbeans

Comment: Patches are generally applied to the development snapshot, not one of the releases. That is how module development is done, with Drupal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you duplicate the file in Netbeans that gets patched (this is important that you do this on the file, **NOT the project**) then right click on it under **Tools -> Apply Diff Patch** then select your patch file. It should then say everything went as planned and allow you a summary.

You will need to repeat this for every file in the patch, or you can just apply it using Git or one of the other methods listed.

Comment: I do everything as you said but it say "the patch cannot be applied in the selected context

Comment: Did you right click JUST the file that gets patched? Nothing else, just the single file.

Comment: Yes, just the file that should be patched. I tried to this on several files that should be patched

Comment: Well then there is a problem with the patch file. If you followed http://www.wdtutorials.com/2012/04/08/drupal-7-how-patch-file-netbeans#.UwzYh5a2t8E it should work