# Integrate simplenews and rules

Tags: 6, rules, emails

I have a website developed in Drupal 6. I am using Simplenews for my newsletter. When a user subscribe to the newsletter I would like to redirect him to a new thank page. In order to do this, I need integrate simplenews module with rules.

In this link https://drupal.org/node/620498 there are several patchs, #40 it works. The point is that I´m not a developer and I don´t know how I do not know how to implement it. I understand I have to create multiple files with these lines of code. I do not know in which folder I have to save the files. Could anyone help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have to close this.  This really belongs in the issue queue.  You should also take a look at the accepted answer to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23347/how-do-i-apply-a-patch-file

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem with an existing module issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you don't really understand what a patch is and how you can use them. You can read about the basics at https://drupal.org/node/620014. Basically, this is a general definition of a patch:

> A "patch file" is a specific kind of file that contains code that is
>   used to modify one or more existing files for a Drupal module.

You can use a special program to apply a patch, but I prefer applying them manually. You can find some more detailed information at https://drupal.org/node/534548.

In the patch you refer to, you find for example

```
+++ simplenews_rules/simplenews_rules.info
@@ -0,0 +1,7 @@
+; $Id$
+name = Simplenews rules
+description = Provides integration with Rules module for Simplenews.
+dependencies[] = simplenews
+dependencies[] = rules
+package = Mail
+core = 6.x
```

That means you should add the code (without the "+" signs) after `@@ -0,0 +1,7 @@` at the top (after the "0th" line) of the `simplenews_rules/simplenews_rules.info` file. If the file doesn't exist yet, simply create it with your favourite code editor at the mentioned directory. I'm using Notepad++, for example.

Comment: This patch adds a new module simplenews_rules inside a simplenews_rules directory of the simplenews module. The files don't exist yet, so if you are manually applying this patch you have to add them. Also see https://drupal.org/patch/apply for information on applying patches in easier ways.

Comment: "but I prefer applying them manually" - you will find when you get really big patches that it definitely is not feasible to apply manually. Why choose that hardest way unless there aren't any easier ways.

Comment: @rooby: You're absolutely right, but in this case, I'd personally apply the patch manually, because it gives you a good grip on what changes were made in the code.

Comment: Thank you! that was my doubt. I had to create the new files in a new directory called simplenews_rules, which is inside simplenews. Actually, it is not a patch, it is a new module. That is the reason I was confused