# Can't upload user picture

Tags: users, files

When I want to add my user picture, the picture can't upload and when I inspect it the link is broken and get this error:

> Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in theme_image_formatter() (line 605 of /home/webpenir/public_html/modules/image/image.field.inc).

However, when I add a picture for another user, it works pretty good.

how can I solve this?

**EDIT**

Only user 1 can't upload but other users can do, which is really strange.

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild permissions?

Comment: Thx for your answer , yes but nothing happend

Answer (score 1):

It is a known issue you can try this [patch](https://drupal.org/files/issues/920840-drupal-image-deleted-10.patch)  and Suppose if that patch not workout for you check the other patches here  https://drupal.org/node/920840  and if any of that patches not solved your issue then the best option is you have to submit a bug report.

Comment: thx for your answer , where should i apply this patch !!! in image module ? i know how to apply a patch .

Comment: Soheil you have to learn on how to apply patch, I usually do only on manual method

Comment: To apply patch check this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23347/how-do-i-apply-a-patch-file

Comment: I do only this method fast and easy, but make sure everything is correct https://drupal.org/node/534548

Comment: Thx for taking your time for me . as i said before i know how to patch , the question is : is this patch for image.module ?

Comment: of course it's for image.module :) sry

Comment: FYI you have to apply patch here /modules/image/image.field.inc

Comment: Could'nt patch it @Bala

Comment: here is what i did : downloaded the patch and put it in image module and run drush and go to module folder and add this commadn "drush apply something.patch"  but i got error :(

Comment: I don't understand! you got error for applying patch or what ? if you got error for applying patch then try the manual method !

Comment: I've patched it but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

I think this is your upload location folder permission problem. please ensure that and give your upload location as public:// folder