# Oops, looks like this request tried to create an infinite loop. We do not allow such things here. We are a professional website!

Tags: views, 7

Every time I use a redirect from an URL alias i receive the foloowing report of:

Oops, looks like this request tried to create an infinite loop. We do not allow such things here. We are a professional website!

Ive tried clearing all the cache and ran cron.

I've tried searching everywhere and can't seem to fix it. Thank you kindly for your support.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug in a contrib module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're using the Redirect mudule, this issue has been posted [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2105063) already.. Installing the latest dev version, and applying [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1796596#comment-8220853) patch should fix it..

Comment: Iam not programmer, How can i apply the patch ??

Comment: @KhalidAhmed search, please. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/23347/16495