# Strict warning: Creating default object

Tags: 7

I am getting this error on my website.

> Strict warning: Creating default object from empty value in theme541_preprocess_html()

I found a patch https://www.drupal.org/node/1242362 by Damien McKenna but I don't know how to apply the patch that fixes the error.

Comment: Hope this link will help you http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23347/how-do-i-apply-a-patch-file

Answer (score 0):

Applying patches is not actually a drupal specific issue and would be better on stack exchange, however there is a drupal documentation page so...

Check out the [applying patches](https://www.drupal.org/patch/apply) documentation.

However having said that, if you read that issue then you can see that patch was committed to that module 3 years ago and if you are using the latest release of the boron module (7.x-1.4) then that patch is already in there.

If you are applying the patch to something that isn't the boron theme then it will likely not work.