# Search API Error on everypage

Tags: search

I am having this very exact issue

https://www.drupal.org/node/2392289

On everypage that I load.
But where to apply this patch?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23347/how-do-i-apply-a-patch-file

Comment: But can I just add the code in the php file my self? And unable to find the file

Comment: You can add patch manually,Please refer [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/534548) it explains how to add patch manually. File name is you need to edit is search_api_page.pages.inc

Comment: well thats exactly the thing.. i am unable to find that file.. so even if i did patching it will fail cause it is not able to find that file

Comment: You are using [Search API Pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_page) module right..? above patch is for this module.

Comment: yes you are correct.but i dont seem to have that file

Comment: actually i am using only Search module not SearchAPI module

Comment: Then you need to see for alternative, this patch is for Search API

Comment: hmm.. but then that is the exact error.. this is  the website.. fxtradingsignals.net