# Getting error after fresh install "Redirects to external URLs are not allowed by default"

Tags: 8, debugging

Playing around with a new install on **localhost.**

Error Happens when I click on a submit button, for example installing new modules.

> Redirects to external URLs are not allowed by default, use
>   \Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse for it.

There are some fixes, [like this one](https://www.drupal.org/node/2643466#comment-10969803) but I don't know how add new hooks and where as I'm a total Drupal newbie.

Comment: Did you apply the patch?

Comment: Not yet as I don't know how to apply and where exactly.

Comment: check http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23347/how-do-i-apply-a-patch-file

Comment: thanks but it didn't work. I applied the patch through PHPstorm. Still getting that error